# Windows Warning Messages for VBA/Sendkeys App

Tags: vba, windows, office365, compiler-warnings, sendkeys

I am trying to do a very simple routine with SendKeys method in VBA to automate opening an app.

The problem is when I try to open a .exe ou .Ink (shortcut) file. The VBA compilation stops and the following message appears "Some files contain viruses that can be harmful to your computer...."

After that I need to select "Ok" or "Cancel" and the aplication doesn't work properly.

I researched a lot but couldn't find any solution. Are there any way to make the message not appear?

I have Windows 10 Home Single Language, Microsoft 365, Excel Version 2107.

See below the code please (The warning message appears in the line "SendKeys (strFile)"):

```
Sub Ligacao()
Dim strOrigem As String
Dim strExtensao As String
Dim strFile As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

strOrigem = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
strExtensao = ".lnk"

strFile = Dir(strOrigem & "*" & strExtensao)


Do While strFile <> ""

  If Mid(strFile, 1, 3) = "Hat" Then

    SendKeys (strFile)
            
  End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, the parenthesis are working. The problem is the message that appears from windows as a Windows's internal safe procedure.

Comment: If you are asking for a way to bypass the windows security, that's not possible. There's probably a better way to do this instead of using `SendKeys`, which should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? I need to auto open some .exe files

Comment: How about using the `Shell` function, since that's what it's used for?

Comment: I will try! One thing that will be necessary after opening the .exe file will be to press "enter" again. Is that possible with Shell function?